# ImportError: No module named libxml2

Tags: python, python-2.7, libxml2

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. I have used libxml2 in my python script and when I try to run it, gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "deploy.py", line 3, in <module>
import libxml2
ImportError: No module named libxml2
```

I tried almost all stackoverflow answers for the same question but nothings solves the issue (Installed several different packages).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to install the package in Ubuntu before being able to use it:

```
sudo apt-get install python-libxml2
```

Comment: i get the message `python-libxml2 is already the newest version (2.9.4+dfsg1-2.2+deb9u2).` and I still get the error: `import libxml2
ImportError: No module named libxml2` - what do I still need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to install [`python-libxml2`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-libxml2).

Note that that's a fairly basic wrapper around the `libxml2` C library. You may want to use [`lxml`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-lxml) instead, for a far more Pythonic XML API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
pip install libxml2-python
```

Comment: pip is a python packaging system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)

Comment: My apologies, I missed that you were using `pip`. Still, the OP is trying to use the Ubuntu packaging system here.

Comment: I'm on OSX, so `pip` should be good, but this command gives me `No distributions at all found for libxml2-python`.

Comment: Not working, error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libxml2-python

Comment: Tried "pip install libxml2-python3" that also not working. error: metadata-generation-failed